# Why doesn't my JQuery event handler remove code work

Tags: jquery

Absolute newbie here...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Foo() {
            d = new Date();
            alert("Hello" + d.getTime());
            alert($('#a1').attr('id'));
            $('#a1').unbind("click");
            $('#a1').off("click");
            $('#a1').unbind();
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {});
    </script>
    <input id='a1' type="button" value="foo" onclick="Foo();" />
</body>
</html>
```

However everytime I click on my foo button it nicely pops up all alerts... totally ignoring my unbind, off, unbind calls.

What would it take to remove the event handler?

My Objective is that when the event handler set by the HTML executes, in the event handler I unbind/unset/undo/off the event handler which has been set by HTML.

Many solutions below kill the event handler totally. but I want to stop if **after** the first click.

I cannot set the event via "one" method. the HTML already has the onclick event.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle?

Comment: How does one make a fiddle?

Comment: You mean that tool called fiddler? is that fiddle?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/ , like this http://jsfiddle.net/86pGD/

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch One makes a fiddle  at: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery's `unbind()` and `off()` apply only to event handlers assigned via jQuery, not to event handler assigned via the `onclick` attribute.

If you want to clear that attribute, you can just do that:

```
$("#a1").removeAttr("onclick");
```

Put into place, it would look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Foo() {
            var d = new Date();
            alert("Hello" + d.getTime());
            alert($('#a1').attr('id'));
            // remove event handler
            $("#a1").removeAttr("onclick");
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {});
    </script>
    <input id='a1' type="button" value="foo" onclick="Foo();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bQ9Lq/

---

If you want an event handler that is only active for one click, then you may want to install the original event handler with jQuery's `.one()` (instead of using onclick) which will automatically remove the event handler after it fires once and you won't even have to write code to remove it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#a1").one("click", function() {
               var d = new Date();
               alert("Hello" + d.getTime());
               alert($('#a1').attr('id'));
           });
        });
    </script>
    <input id='a1' type="button" value="foo" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does not work. I am aware of one keyword. My actual usecase is that I am trying to remove an event which was assosiated by the use of onclick. 

Your suggestion kills the event totally. so even the first click doesn't work.

my objective is that inside the first click, I disable the event handler which was set by onclick in HTML.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch - uHHH, you put the `removeAttr()` line IN your function when you want to remove the event handler.  It does work.

Comment: let's say that the HTML WILL contain onclick and you cannot change that. now how will you achieve what I want.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch - see the edit to the first half of my answer.  It appears you didn't read or understand that so now I've spelled it out with an exact version of your code.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch - I've even added a working jsFiddle demo to show you it works.

Comment: yes it works! thank you so much. You won't believe it that I spent 2 hours with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using inlined event handler, just remove the onclick attribute

```
function Foo() {
    d = new Date();
    alert("Hello" + d.getTime());
    alert($('#a1').attr('id'));
    $('#a1').removeAttr("onclick");
}
```

Comment: @Alexander after the first click.... I think OP wants to call the method only once

Comment: doesn't work. the event has to be removed after the first click.

Answer (score 0):

You did not bind with `jQuery` so **do not unbind with jQuery** rather unbind with javascript, you would need indexer or [get()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WU3ce/)**

```
$('#a1')[0].onclick = null;
```

or

```
$('#a1').get(0).onclick = null;;
```

You can unbind using `attr()`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WU3ce/1/)**

```
 $('#a1').attr("onclick", "");
```

Comment: Why do you do [0] why not just $('#a1').onclick = null;?

Comment: Because selector gives you jQuery object and onclick is javascript attribute

Comment: You unbind after first click, you would get for first time only check the demo

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#a1" ).bind( "click", function() {
        d = new Date();
        alert("Hello" + d.getTime());
        alert($('#a1').attr('id'));
        $('#a1').unbind("click");
    });
 });

<input id='a1' type="button" value="foo" />
```

Comment: This isn't the issue.